# How to pass value from mainview to subview Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

**Main View**

```
     events: {
    "click .open-sku-details":"openSkuDetails"

  },
  openSkuDetails: function(ev) {
    var self = this;
      var sku_id = $(ev.target).attr('sku_id');
      self.skuDetailsModel.set("id",sku_id);
      self.skuDetailsModel.fetch({
      }).done(function (response) {
      });

      this.skuDetails = new skuDetailsView({model:self.skuDetailsModel});
      return this.skuDetails.render();

  }
```

**SubView**

```
    var $ = jQuery = require('jquery'),
  Backbone = require('backbone'),
  Handlebars = require('handlebars'),
  _ = require('underscore'),
  skuDetailsTemplate = require("../../templates/product/SkuDetails.html"),
  skuDetailsModel = require('../../models/product/SkuDetailsModel');
var SkuDetailsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: ".sku-details-container",
  tagName:"div",

  initialize: function () {
    var self = this;
    this.skuDetailsModel = new skuDetailsModel();
    this.listenTo(self.skuDetailsModel, 'add', self.render);
    this.listenTo(self.skuDetailsModel, 'change', self.render);
     self.skuDetailsModel.fetch({
      }).done(function (response) {
      });
  },
  render: function () {
    var self = this;
    this.$el.html(skuDetailsTemplate({
      skuDetails: self.skuDetailsModel.toJSON(),
    }));
  }

});

module.exports = SkuDetailsView;
```

How do i pass the `id` value from one view two another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it via [the options argument](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor).

In your main view

```
this.skuDetails = new skuDetailsView({
    model:self.skuDetailsModel,
    sku_id: sku_id
});
```

In your sub view

```
initialize: function (options) {
    var sku_id = options.sku_id;
}
```

The options object is only available in the initialize function. Store it, for instance with `this.sku_id = options.sku_id`, if you need it when rendering.

Of course, you could also pass it via the model as an attribute, but if it's just view-related it makes more sense to pass it as an option.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sku_id' of undefined